# Why does Dolphin Emulator randomly freeze?

Tags: emulation, super-mario-galaxy-2, dolphin-emulator

for some reason, when I was playing Dolphin 5.0, my game (Super Mario Galaxy 2 but this happens with all games) randomly freezes. I don't know what happened and there were no answers for how to fix this on the web (and yes I know I should upgrade to the dev versions but they are super buggy and unstable so yeah). Can someone help me please :-)?

Answer (score 0):

The freezes could be caused by Shader Compilation.

> The slowdown when loading new areas, effects, models, and more is commonly referred to as "Shader Compilation Stuttering," by users and developers alike... Typically a stutter only lasts a couple of frames, but on really demanding scenes with multiple compiling shaders, stutters of over a second are possible. - *[Ubershaders: A Ridiculous Solution to an Impossible Problem](https://dolphin-emu.org/blog/2017/07/30/ubershaders/)*

You can eliminate the shuttering by using the Ubershaders option introduced in Dolphin 5.0-4869 and later.

[image: Graphics options, selected 'Asynchronous (Ubershaders)']

(For more info, [refer to the Dolphin Blog](https://dolphin-emu.org/blog/2017/07/30/ubershaders/))

Comment: Sorry for the VERY late answer, but I finally started to use the dev versions. Turns out dev versions are rubbish on mac but ok on windows.